# Can an Ext.data.JsonPStore Host (base url) be set?

Tags: extjs

Is it possible, in Ext 6.5.3, to set the JsonPStore root url so that the config parameter ‘url’ value gets automatically  appended?

Comment: use onBeforeLoad and add it to the extraParms. Other than that you might want to dive deeper into an override to Ext.data.Connection.

Comment: Wouldn’t be prudent to award the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go:

Either in your store

```
stores: {
    myStore: {
        type: 'testStore',
        listeners: {
            beforeload: function(store, operation) {
                // either this works
                store.getProxy().setUrl('newUrl');
                // or you can try
                operation.setUrl('newUrl');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can try to use a global apporach...

either via onBeforeLaunch in the `Application.js`

```
onBeforeLaunch() {
   // redirect all calls to api url
   Ext.Ajax.addListener('beforerequest', function (conn, options) {
       options.url = Core.APIURL + options.url;
   });

   this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

or via `Ext.data.Connection` event `beforerequest`

Comment: The second option is mainly correct, but you’d have to override Ext.data.JsonP or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The config parameter ‘url’ value gets automatically appended.If set JsonPStore in root  *url* .

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('YourStoreId');
store.getProxy().setUrl('your url');
```